# Overwrite Local Notifications

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a method that activates a local notification.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = [mainTitle text];
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

The problem is that if you call several times the method, do not overwrite the localNotif, but it adds another. How do I delete the old every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make `localNotif` a property or instance variable of the class that contains this method.

Comment: Thanks, how do I save a variable though?

Comment: You mean like across application launches? There are a number of ways to make objects persistent, but the simplest is probably [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). To save something you do `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:localNotif forKey:@"myNotification"]` and to retrieve it you would do `UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myNotification"]`.

Comment: I forgot the most important thing: you have to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` when you're done to save your changes.

Comment: One last thing: there is conflict between variables and writing order. Last one help?

Comment: I don't think you can save a `UILocalNotification` in user defaults, as it's not one of the standard plist types.

Answer (score 2):

Save the local notification object (say in an ivar), and do:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:previousNotification];
```

You can also clear all local notifications with `cancelAllLocalNotifications`.

Comment: Thanks, how do I save a variable though?

Comment: In an instance variable...  If you need to store it across app launches for some reason, `UILocalNotification` conforms to `NSCoding` so you can do something like `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:localNotif toFile:pathToFile]`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The question is: "How do I delete the old every time?"